# d3.js con datos JSON no carga

Tags: json, csv, d3.js

Estoy haciendo una grafica linear con d3.js. Si cargo los datos desde un JSON exterior, no me los carga.

```
function cargarDatos(){
d3.json('datos.json', function (data) {
    datos = data;
    console.log(datos)
})
```

}

Un archivo CSV si que me deja, y si hago esto, los datos JSON si funcionan.

```
    function cargarDatos(){
d3.csv('datos.json', function (data) {
    datos = data;
    console.log(datos)
})
```

}

De esta forma, los datos JSON si los veo, pero no entiendo el por que. El JSON es correcto.

```
[
{
    "dato":1
},
{
    "dato":12
},
{
    "dato":19
},
{
    "dato":33
},
{
    "dato":41
}
```

]

Y este es mi CSV que tambien funciona.

```
nombre,numero,edad
Mariano,1,2
Carla,3,4
Max,5,6
Maria,7,8
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, por si interesa. Cuando coge el JSON, hay que hacer todo lo demas dentro de la funcion, sino, pierde los datos.              d3.csv('datos.json', function (data) {
    datos = data;
    console.log(datos)
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo has puesto en tu comentario pero lo pongo aquí para que sea más visible.

Al cargar el JSON los datos son visibles únicamente dentro de la función, debido al "scope" de la variable.

Si quisiera tener datos persistentes, podrías declarar una variable fuera de ese llamada a la función (que sea visible para la función) y asignarle los datos:

```js
var the_data = [];

function loadData(){
  d3.json('datos.json', function (data) {
     the_data = data;   
  });
}
loadData();
console.log(the_data);
```